# python - Weird unclear error with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

site = "https://blockchain.info/wallet/login"
identifier = "myIdentifier"


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(site)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/input'.send_keys(identifier)
```

I run it and I get this error:
[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/897fe2b83db36585b3521cc1a06aa832.png))</sub>

Bigger image: http://gyazo.com/897fe2b83db36585b3521cc1a06aa832

I tried things like comment after that line, moving it up and down but I don't know what the problem is here

Comment: Don't know if that's it, but parentheses don't match in your last line. You might want to add a closing one before `send_keys`?

Comment: That's an image of your code, what error are you seeing?

Comment: @usmcs, the only error was "invalid syntax", but as dunno said, I left out a parentheses

Comment: this long lines are a perfect demo why coding standards like pep8 are good. If the lines where broken and properly indented the OP would have seen he's problem much quicker.

Comment: I believe when the IDE places a red line, it means there is a syntax error. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/input'.send_keys(identifier)
```

with:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/input').send_keys(identifier)
```

Watch the closing `)` - first find an element, then send keys to it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing Parentheses.
Try this.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(site)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/input').send_keys(identifier)
```